# adding colors to a Gradient Panel in java?

Tags: java, gradient

How to adding new colors to our gradient panel in java?

Comment: What kind of `Gradient Panel` are you talking about?

Comment: if someone have managed to create a remote brain reader, I think @Venkats would like to play the guinea pig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

extend  your panel from JPanel and override it's paintComponent like this.

```
    @Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
// Creates a two-stops gradient
GradientPaint p;
p = new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(0xFFFFFF),
0, getHeight(), new Color(0xC8D2DE));
// Saves the state
Paint oldPaint = g2.getPaint();
// Paints the background
g2.setPaint(p);
g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
// Restores the state
g2.setPaint(oldPaint);
// Paints borders, text...
super.paintComponent(g);
}
}
```

and you see the color  object  you can change existing color...

and i advise you to read

> Filthy Rich Clients

and get this  book from somewhere.it has more usefull information which you can may use of learn.

Comment: You might want to add a link to where you copied this from: `DepthButton` at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/TwoStopsGradient.htm ?